# Error in paster setup-app development.ini?

Tags: python

I am trying to install MediaCore on my machine running CentOS as soon as I fire this coomand

on command prompt it gives me an error

```
[root@localhost mediacore-mediacore-e6e7419]# paster setup-app development.ini Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/paster", line 7, in ?
    sys.exit( File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.4.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 84, in run  invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.4.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 123, in invoke   exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.4.egg/paste/script/appinstall.py", line 68, in run   return super(AbstractInstallCommand, self).run(new_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.4.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 218, in run   result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.4.egg/paste/script/appinstall.py", line 447, in command   conf = appconfig(config_spec, relative_to=os.getcwd())   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 215, in appconfig    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 248, in loadcontext     global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 278, in _loadconfig  return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 409, in get_context  section)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 430, in _context_from_use  context = self.get_context(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 361, in get_context global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 248, in loadcontext global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 285, in _loadegg return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 560, in get_context   entry_point, protocol, ep_name = self.find_egg_entry_point(  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 587, in find_egg_entry_point
    possible.append((entry.load(), protocol, entry.name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load  entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/root/medi/mediacore-mediacore-e6e7419/mediacore/config/middleware.py", line 19, in ?  from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Beaker-1.6.1-py2.4.egg/beaker/middleware.py", line 11, in ? from beaker.cache import CacheManager
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Beaker-1.6.1-py2.4.egg/beaker/cache.py", line 17, in ?   import beaker.ext.memcached as memcached
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Beaker-1.6.1-py2.4.egg/beaker/ext/memcached.py", line 136   with self.pool.reserve() as mc:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [with statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) only appeared in python2.5, and you're using python2.4. It looks that Beaker is not really compatible with python2.4.